# "WebGL: context lost." error in MapLibre GL JS with Tauri

Tags: webkit, webgl, react-map-gl, tauri, maplibre-gl

I get these following errors when trying to run MapLibre GL JS in my Tauri App:

```
[Error] WebGL: context lost.
    getContext
    (anonymous function) (maplibre-gl.js:9404)
    (anonymous function) (maplibre-gl.js:9405)
    (anonymous function) (maplibre-gl.js:9414)
    i (maplibre-gl.js:9416)
    (anonymous function) (react-map-gl.js:838)
```

And the next error:

```
[Error] Error: Map is not supported by this browser
    (anonymous function) (react-map-gl.js:862)
```

I start my app with `npm run tauri dev`. If I use `npm run dev` and run the app in the browser, everything works fine.

I am aware that this might be a WebGL issue but I don't how to tackle it in a desktop app such as Tauri since I am actually from a web development background.

I use [React Map GL](https://visgl.github.io/react-map-gl/) as a wrapper on top of this library.

Any help is much appreciated. My code:

```
import Map from "react-map-gl";
import maplibregl from "maplibre-gl";
import "maplibre-gl/dist/maplibre-gl.css";

export default function MapLibreExample() {

    return (
        <div className="MapLibre">
            <Map
                style={{ width: "1200px", height: "70vh" }}
                mapStyle={{
                    version: 8,
                    glyphs: "http://localhost:5173/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf",
                    sources: {
                        // ...sources
                    },
                    layers: [
                        // ...layers
                    ]
                }}
                mapLib={maplibregl}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: What OS are you building with?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu, it turns out that this issue is known: https://github.com/tauri-apps/tauri/issues/6559